# increase size of scrollbar react-custom-scrollbar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scrollbar

I am using [the react-scrollbar](https://github.com/malte-wessel/react-custom-scrollbars) library which [contains demos here](http://malte-wessel.github.io/react-custom-scrollbars/).

I am trying to figure out how to increase the size of the scrollbar but am having difficulties

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Scrollbars } from 'react-custom-scrollbars';

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Scrollbars
                style={{ width: 300 }}>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                <p>Lorem consetetur</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum anctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            </Scrollbars>
        );
    }
}
```

`width` here changes the width of the actually `div` and not the scrollbar.

Does anyone know how to increase the width of the actual scrollbar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `renderThumbVertical`

```
<Scrollbars
    renderThumbVertical={({ style, ...props }) =>
        <div {...props} style={{ ...style, width: '60px' }}/>
}>

 <p>Content</p>

</Scrollbars>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it happen that you couldn't make it work !

Then know that you need to provide the base styling. Check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54973078/7668448